# Amazon mws: get fulfilled shipments report

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I am trying to get this report using the API: 
SellerCentral>Reports>Fulfillment>Amazon Fulfilled Shipments

Currently the report is downloaded daily from the seller central web interface. Is it possible to get this report via the API?

I don't mind (even prefer) using boto or other mws related python packages.

This [page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200592790) says it should be possible, but doesn't provide any reference how to call the api and get the report:

> In addition to downloading the report, sellers with developer
>   capability can use Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) to
>   request the report.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking for is the [documentation for the MWS Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html).

Use the [MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Bill is correct.  Understand the flowchart on the link he posted (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html) and then make the appropriate MWS calls.  Basically, request it, poll it to see if it's completed, then retrieve it and do what you need to do with it.  You can use their client libraries, which do most of the work, right here:
https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/139-2745849-3030362?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest